# CS1061 error on linked button in bootstrap webform

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I am new to webforms and am getting an error while trying to compile webform1.aspx which is a form next to the site master form:

I am trying to get in my headers and footers and the fixed set of navigation buttons in my webpage

I am getting the following error:

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'site1_master' does not contain a definition for 'LinkButton4_Click' and no accessible extension method 'LinkButton4_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'site1_master' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 55:                      
Line 56:                          
Line 57:                              <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton4" runat="server"
Line 58:                                  OnClick="LinkButton4_Click">View Books</asp:LinkButton>
Line 59:

Source File: D:\KUD Venkat\source\repos\ELibraryManagement\LibraryManagementSystem\Site1.Master    Line: 57

Here is my code for Site1.master:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    
   <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <link href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <!-- Datatable css -->
    <link href="DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <!-- FontAwesome css -->
    <link href="FontAwesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    
   <!-- Bootstrap Bundle -->
    <script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Popper js -->
    <script src="Bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Bootstrap js -->
    <script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

             <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                 <img src="imgs/books.png" width="30" height="30"/>
                 E-Library
                </a>

                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
                     aria-controls="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                  </button>

                 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                         <li class="nav-item active">
                             <a class="nav-link" href="homepage.aspx">Home</a>
                         </li>
                         <li class="nav-item active">
                             <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                         </li>
                         <li class="nav-item active">
                             <a class="nav-link" href="#">Terms</a>
                         </li>
                     </ul>
                     <ul class="navbar-nav">
                         <li class="nav-item active">
                             <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton4" runat="server"
                                 OnClick="LinkButton4_Click">View Books</asp:LinkButton>

                         </li>
                         <li class="nav-item active">
                             <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
                                 OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">User Login</asp:LinkButton>

                         </li>
                         <li class="nav-item active">
                             <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"
                                 OnClick="LinkButton2_Click">Sign Up</asp:LinkButton>

                         </li>
                         <li class="nav-item active">
                             <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton3" runat="server"
                                 OnClick="LinkButton3_Click">Logout</asp:LinkButton>

                         </li>
                         <li class="nav-item active">
                             <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" ID="LinkButton7" runat="server"
                                 OnClick="LinkButton7_Click">Hello user</asp:LinkButton>

                         </li>
                     </ul>

                 </div>

             </nav>

        </div>

        <!-- Main Content Place Holder-->
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <!-- Main Content Place Holder-->

        <footer>
            <p> &copy All right Reserved. <a class="footerlinks" href="#" 
         target="_blank">TataSteel</a> </p>
        </footer>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My code in Web Form1.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="LibraryManagementSystem.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <h1>
        This is our Content webform
    </h1>
</asp:Content>
```

I am trying to get in my header and footer and the corresponding menu buttons. However I am getting the error. What could be wrong . Could you help?

The solution should have the headers and footers along with the navigation buttons.

Comment: You have `LinkButton4_Click` method in code behind of master page?

Comment: yes I saw that and changed it